# Difference between two different variable declarations in asm

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

What's the difference between the following `gas` assembly?

```
x: .long 500
```

And:

```
x = 500
```

Can both be used interchangeably or, if not, why is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re not interchangeable. The first one:

```
    x:    .long 500
```

creates a 4-byte space in memory initialized with the given value. The label `x` represents the address of that memory location.

The second one:

```
    x = 500
```

doesn’t create any memory. It sets the symbol `x` to the value 500, not to an address.

Comment: thanks, how is the label/value 'stored' them? Doesn't it have to get into memory one way or another?

Comment: The symbol value (the label address in the first case) is only stored in the assembler symbol table. It is not stored in the program being generated. When the symbol is used in an instruction, the assembler uses the symbol value to generate the instruction.

Comment: @carl.hiass: Note that `x = 500` won't appear in the "symbol table" of the object output of the assembler.  It's probably better to think of it as an "assemble time constant".  Technically I think GAS terminology still calls it a symbol, but it's not the same kind of symbol created by a label.  Anyway, you use it for stuff like `add $x, %eax`, instead of hard-coding the same number in multiple places.

Comment: @Peter, symbols created with “=” do appear in the symbol table, and they can be made global with the .global directive.